# Assign the result of a loop to a variable in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Consider a list I want to parse using a `for` :

```
friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]
for i in friends:
   print i
```

will return :

```
"Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"
```

However, if I want to put it to a (str) variable, like :

```
friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]
for i in friends:
    var=i
```

first I have to declare another `var` variable, which is silly but whatever.
then,

```
print var
```

will return the last element of the list, which is "Paris", because the variable is overwritten for each iteration right.

So my question is : how can I assign the output of my loop "i", for each iteration, to a variable in Python ?

Sorry for the sillyness of this question but this is a concept I can't seem to figure out clearly.

Comment: why cant u try with a dictionary?

Comment: The answer is probably quite trivial, but I fail to understand what exactly you're asking for. Could you elaborate? What result do you expect?  Note that the first example will **not** result in the output you claim...

Comment: And what would be the names of the variables?

Comment: In terms of result : do you see the result of `print i` ? I would simply have the result of this print to a variable.

Comment: What do you mean *"to a variable"*? You already have a list, which is assigned to a variable. What variables would you like the items to be assigned to, *and why?*

Comment: To be completely correct, *printing* and *returning* are two distinct concepts.  Your loop doesn't *return* anything.

Comment: You already have each element in the list stored as a variable: the original list itself.

Comment: I think my question is unclear, so I will re-formulate my question in an other post. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well, you'd like to dynamically create variables. Here it is.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]
d = OrderedDict()
for idx, value in enumerate(friends):
    key = 'var' + str(idx)
    d[key] = value 

print(d)
# Output
OrderedDict([('var0', 'Joe'), ('var1', 'Zoe'), ('var2', 'Brad'), ('var3', 'Angelina'), ('var4', 'Zuki'), ('var5', 'Thandi'), ('var6', 'Paris')])
```

Comment: wouldn't list(enumerate(friends)) be easier/clearer here?

Comment: @Skirrebattie, I don't think so.  `for idx, v in enumerate(l)` is widely used.

Comment: Look at your `OrderedDict`. Now look at `friends`. Note how you have used several lines of codes to reinvent the `list` type. The OP's question is fundamentally flawed and any answers cannot possibly be reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

I also have this question, this is how I managed to solve it somewhat:

```
    friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]

    new_friends = ' '.join([x for x in friends])

    print(new_friends)
```

Will return:

```
    Joe Zoe Brad Angelina Zuki Thandi Paris
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var = ''
friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]
for i in friends:
    var=i
```

if list and loop are in function then declare var as global

```
global var
```

in starting of function

Comment: This is wrong, as the original question doesn't want `var` to have the last assignment, but all values.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest & cleanest way for you would be a "List Comprehension", see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp).

Here is the respective code:

```
friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]      
var = [(i) for i in friends]
```

Should do what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the values in `friends` into a comma-separated string, that would be

```
s = ','.join(friends)
```

If you want to include quotes around the names, maybe something like

```
s = ','.join(['"{0}"'.format(x) for x in friends])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of the loop:

```
the_variable = the_variable + i
```

However, if you are to do this, you should add a space to the end of every item in the dictionary, otherwise it will output:

```
JoeZoeBradAngelinaZukiThandiParis
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary instead, as I too spent a while looking into this, and determined that a dictionary would be easy enough.

```
    friends = ["Joe", "Zoe", "Brad", "Angelina", "Zuki", "Thandi", "Paris"]
    dict= {}
    for i in friends:
       dict[i] = i

    print(dict)
    print(dict['Zuki'])
    dict['Zuki'] = "Tim Smith"

    print(dict['Zuki'])
```

The Other option would be to just call the number:

```
    print(friends[0])
```

As for automatic assignment I haven't found a way to do it.